How to read a FAT (not FAT32) formatted Floppy Disc?
I have some old 1.44 Mb Floppy Discs and  have purchased a Generic USB Disc Drive but it won't read the discs.
I am running Windows10 on lap top.
Tried all youTube vids!!
Frustrated English Silver Surfer

The disks are likely unreadable.

Can you try some new (old stock) 1.44 Mb Floppy Discs and see if you access some different floppy discs with the drive and Windows 10? I.e. to try and determine if the old discs are unreadable v.s. the generic USB disc drive doesn't work with Windows 10.
